# how to I pass parameter to delete request in guzzle

Tags: php, symfony, curl

I am using guzzle as http client for testing my symfony api.

There is url option given in documentation,but how do I pass userid & api id parameter so this can delete a particular record of particular user.

When I tested with curl

> curl -i -X DELETE http://localhost/us/serenify/web/app_dev.php/userapi/delete/1/6

My api is working fine showing appropriate responses.

But I am not able to test it with guzzle as I am unable to find option for  passing my parameter.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: http://localhost/us/serenify/web/app_dev.php/userapi/delete/1/7/  This is my api user where 1 is user id & 7 is api id.    I have tried $request = $client->createRequest('delete', 'http://localhost/us/serenify/web/app_dev.php/userapi/delete/1/7/');   This its now working. I tried $request = $client->createRequest('delete', 'http://localhost/us/serenify/web/app_dev.php/userapi/delete/'); & try to pass paramter though setField but its not working.   If you have any example to pass data please let me know.

Comment: You want to embed parameter to url or want to pass them from 1 page to other as http get/post request?

Comment: I am creating api. Above is my api url. I just want to pass two parameter to my url ,but those does not require a query string as I am using MVC structure,My controller function needs two parameter.  I have tested api through curl ,its working fine. But I want to test this through guzzle as per client requirement.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that defines and executes your Symfony route:

```
{
    "operations": {
        "deleteEntity": {
            "httpMethod": "DELETE",
            "uri": "/userapi/delete/{userid}/{apiid}",
            "summary": "Deletes an entity",
            "parameters": {
                "userid": {
                    "location": "query"
                },
                "apiid": {
                    "location": "query"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the code:

```
class MyApi
{
    protected $client;

    public function __construct(ClientInterface $client, $baseUrl)
    {
        $this->client = $client;

        //tell the client what the base URL to use for the request
        $this->client->setBaseUrl($baseUrl);

        //fill the client with all the routes
        $description = ServiceDescription::factory("/path/to/routes.json");
        $this->client->setDescription($description);
    }

    public function deleteEntity($userId, $apiId)
    {
        $params = array(
            'userid' => $userId,
            'apiid' => $apiId
        );

        $command = $this->client->getCommand('deleteEntity', $params);
        $command->prepare();

        $response = $this->client->execute($command);

        return $response;
    }
}

$client = new Guzzle\Service\Client();

$api = new MyApi($client, ' http://localhost/us/serenify/web/app_dev.php');
$api->deleteEntity(1, 6);
```

Now, as it currently stands, the generated route would look something like

**http://localhost/us/serenify/web/app_dev.php/userapi/delete?userid=1&apiid=6**.

If you want the parameters not to be passed by Guzzle as query paramters, but instead like URL parameters, all you have to do is change their type in the JSON definition file from **query** to **uri**.

PS: I did NOT test the code above. Might work out-of-the-box or it might not. Minor tweaks may be required.

Comment: Hi guys I found a way, there is no need to do anything. I have implemented in different way. <code>  public function testDeleteAction()
    {
      $client = new Client(); 
      $request = $client->createRequest('Delete', 'http://localhost/us/serenify/web/app_dev.php/userapi/delete/2/22');
      $response = $client->send($request);
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($response);        
      echo "</pre>";
      exit;
    } </code>

Comment: @hiteshrane You're hardcoding the values in the URL, not quite ideal. Take a look at my code above, a different URL will be generated based on the parameters you give to the `MyApi::deleteEntity()` method. This is much better and maintainable.